# Resize Image on workbook sheet does not work in apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am using newest apache poi dependency and want to resize image (to not have it so so big after workbook opened):

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

1. I created new workbook as .xlsm and didnt change default font (it is Calibri 11 px) according to documentation.
2. downloaded image from pexels: [Link To Pexels Image](https://www.pexels.com/pl-pl/zdjecie/natura-srodowisko-widok-z-lotu-ptaka-zdjecie-lotnicze-12850802/)
3. used code like here:

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.*;

public class ImageResizer {

    public static  void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        ImageResizer resizer = new ImageResizer();
    }
    public ImageResizer() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        XSSFSheet sheet = null;
        Cell cell = null;
        XSSFRow sheetRow = null;

        try {
            File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Luke\\Downloads\\TestWorkbook_AddingImage.xlsm");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        FileInputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream( "C:\\Users\\Luke\\Downloads\\pexels-yura-forrat-12850802.jpg" );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        final int pictureIndex = workbook.addPicture( stream, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        stream.close();

        anchor.setCol1( 0 );
        anchor.setRow1( 0);
        final Picture pict = drawing.createPicture( anchor, pictureIndex );
        pict.resize(0.1,0.1);

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Luke\\Downloads\\TestWorkbook_AddingImage_Saved.xlsm");
        workbook.write(os);
        os.close();
        System.out.println("Done!");

        }

    }
```

And pict.resize(0.1, 0.1) method is making my picture very, very small (inside cell is only barely seen dot). I tried also with 0.5, 0.9 and even 2.0 but result is all the same.
Why? What can i do to resize picture?

Best,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in [Picture.resize(double scaleX, double scaleY)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Picture.html#resize-double-double-) and [Picture.resize(double scale)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Picture.html#resize-double-) when either `ClientAnchor.Col1` or `ClientAnchor.Row1` or both are 0. It works when both of the top left anchor cell indexes are greater than 0.

A workaround is to use `Picture.resize()` first, before resizing with scale. `Picture.resize()` first calculates the bottom right anchor position to fit the full native picture size. After that `Picture.resize(double scaleX, double scaleY)` works properly.

```
...
        anchor.setCol1(0);
        anchor.setRow1(0);
        final Picture pict = drawing.createPicture( anchor, pictureIndex );
        pict.resize();
        pict.resize(0.1, 0.1);
...
```

Comment: o wow @Axel Richter great answer! Thank you very much!